# Check for exception in python's subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, shell, exception, subprocess, popen

I am using python's `subprocess.Popen` to run shell processes (using `shell=True`).

I am not using `subprocess.check_output` because I don't want to block and I want to continuously get back the stdout of the process, which I can do by iterating over the `Popen`'s `stdout` member.

Is there a way to check for exceptions/errors that happen in `Popen` (with `shell=True`)?

I would like to have a similar convenience as the one in `check_output`, in which exceptions bubble up as `CalledProcessError`.

Comment: You could check, if `.returncode` is `0`, otherwise consider it as an error

Comment: My problem is that I don't quite understand the behavior of the completion of popen. I thought it started a process and it would run until completion and I could simply check `.returncode`, but if I just check `.returncode` in a loop, if will run forever giving always `None`. While for example if I iterate over the process' `stdout`, it will complete eventually.